# Lost almost 40GB of free space after Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro. Any ideas?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I make upgrade from Windows 7 Pro to Windows 10 Pro about week ago. There was around 48 GB free on C:. Since then the free space constantly decreases (today is 8 GB). I did not install any software which take a lot of space.

Any ideas how to track the problem? Or how to find out which is eating space?

I did not remove Upgrade files, so I can return to windows 7.

REMARK:
I have 48 GB free (with not include upgrade files) after the upgrade. I know that I can delete those, but I need to know how each day free space decreases - I have not such problem with Windows 7 Pro!

Comment: Use WinDirStat or similar program to map your disk usage.

Comment: 10x, @Ramhound. I will try. You can add this as answer. In my case it seems appropriate. Today the free space is 7GB, again.

Comment: It already exists as an answer to another question, one, that is normally used as a duplicate to this type of question.

Comment: 10x @Ramhound. I did not found similar question. If you can delete it (I can not, because there are answers) or mark it as duplicate. I found issue using the utility you suggested to me. My Seach folder is 35GB in size. I will post answer with the solution that works for me.

Comment: I can't delete questions and would not even if I could, vote to close as a duplicate, is the only correct action

Answer (score 1):

When you upgrade Windows, it keeps an old copy of the former version of Windows on the machine in case you want to revert back.  There is a way to claim some of this space back.  Do note though, that **you will not be able to go back to your previous version of Windows.**

- Search for Administrative Tools in the search feature
- Double Click Disk Cleanup and select the drive you want to clean (Likely C:)
- Click Clean up system files and select the drive again
- In the List at the top, you'll see some items in the GBs of size.  I'm not sure of the exact names of them (Possibly something like Previous Version of Windows and some other ones like Upgrade Logs).  Select the items you want to delete, then click Ok.  The disk cleaner will remove these files, and you'll get your space back.

Comment: Sorry @TimmyJim , but this is not the case - I know that I have 77 GB old files, but my problem is outside of those files. After the upgrade I have 48 GB free. Now I have 8 GB free.

Comment: How much space are you losing each day?

Comment: I did not measure it each day, but after a 2nd or 3rd day it was 28. And today it was 8GB. I restarted and uninstalled a software DML Dashboard (Red Gate) and it is 17 GB now, but it is far from 48 GB, just after the upgrade, @TimmyJim.

Comment: Although I personally haven't seen 20Gb changes like you have, I have noticed smaller change (~1-3Gb) in my space on my hard drive over courses of days.  I do know that deleting the files as my answer specifies will get you back probably around 20Gb, but if you don't want to delete those files in case you want to go back,  then it is what it is.

Comment: 10x, I will wait a bit, before making clean up of old Installation.

Answer (score 1):

10x to @Ramhound comment (to use WinDirStat) I found the issue - my `Search` folder was 35GB in size. Using this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2838018) I rebuild the index.